# Maclaurin expansion of $\frac{1}{1+x^2}$ by substituting x with $\tan{y}$

Tags: derivatives, taylor-expansion

I am trying to find Maclaurin expansion of $\frac{1}{1+x^2}$ and thinking I can substitute x with $\tan{y}$.
Then the function becomes ${\cos^2y}$.

And the expansion should look like this;

$f(0)=1$

$f'(0)=-2\sin{y}\cos{y}=0$

$f''(0)=-2(\cos^2y-\sin^2y)=-2$

$f^{(3)}(0) = 0$

$f^{(4)}(0) = 8$
...

Finally the expansion should be like this, which is not correct.

$\sum_{n=0}^\infty(-1)^n\frac{2^{n-1}}{n!}y^{2n}$

What am I wrong here?

Comment: Your strategy only works if you write $\cos^2y$ as a series in $\tan y$, not $y$.

Comment: Then you will need and use the Maclaurin series of $\tan x$?